# SQL Calculate Total Time A Vehicle Is Off/On Road

Tags: sql

I hope I do this right, first time posting.  The below query gives the On/Off Road Status of a single vehicle over time

```
SELECT
   VASH1.RecordID,
   VASH1.VehicleAssetID,
   VASH1.UpdateStatusID,
   VASH1.UpdateStatusDate
FROM 
   dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH1
WHERE
   VASH1.VehicleAssetID = '45793'
ORDER BY
   VASH1.UpdateStatusDate`
```

Returning the following dataset:

```
Record  Vehicle Update          Update
ID       Asset   Status          Status
         ID      ID              Date
8720     45793    2              2016-12-21 12:31:51.893
16087    45793    2              2019-02-05 10:57:00.000
16711    45793    2              2019-03-27 14:15:00.000
16717    45793    2              2019-03-28 07:45:00.000
16956    45793    2              2019-04-10 20:00:00.000
17124    45793    2              2019-04-18 11:53:00.000
19592    45793    3              2019-06-06 08:58:00.000
19651    45793    3              2019-06-07 12:00:00.000
21030    45793    2              2019-06-12 15:00:00.000
20702    45793    3              2019-06-28 14:12:00.000
31711    45793    3              2019-07-18 08:27:00.000
43226    45793    2              2019-08-19 07:31:00.000
43274    45793    3              2019-08-19 14:30:00.000
43434    45793    2              2019-08-19 15:00:00.000
43349    45793    3              2019-08-21 09:00:00.000
43500    45793    3              2019-08-27 06:30:00.000
43526    45793    2              2019-08-27 10:00:00.000
43718    45793    2              2019-08-30 14:32:00.000
44214    45793    3              2019-09-11 11:30:00.000
44229    45793    2              2019-09-11 13:23:00.000
44854    45793    3              2019-09-24 12:30:00.000
44942    45793    2              2019-09-25 21:00:00.000
44988    45793    3              2019-09-27 07:00:00.000
45020    45793    2              2019-09-27 13:50:00.000
45496    45793    3              2019-10-08 12:00:00.000
45509    45793    2              2019-10-08 14:04:00.000
```

Update Status ID 2 = On Road and Update Status ID 3 = Off Road.  **I want to calculate and return the total time (in minutes) this vehicle has been OFF THE ROAD and ON THE ROAD (single value for each, separate queries is preferred as it is part of a larger query).**

The closest I have come is the following, where I've managed to calculate a running total of the On Road times, in minutes.  My next step with to aggregate this to give the total but it fails because I can't aggregate with an aggregation in the select and also sub-selects.  I was then hoping to figure out the total Off-Road time:

```
    SELECT
       VASH1.RecordID,
       VASH1.VehicleAssetID,
       VASH1.UpdateStatusID,
       VASH1.UpdateStatusDate,
       CASE 
              --If last UpdateStatusDate (previous to this one) has an UpdateStatusID of 2 then it calculates the time between that last UpdateStatusDate and this one
              WHEN (SELECT UpdateStatusID FROM Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH2 WHERE VASH2.VehicleAssetID=VASH1.VehicleAssetID AND VASH2.UpdateStatusDate =
                           (SELECT MAX(VASH3.UpdateStatusDate) FROM Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH3 WHERE VASH3.VehicleAssetID=VASH1.VehicleAssetID AND VASH3.UpdateStatusDate<VASH1.UpdateStatusDate))=2
                     THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (SELECT MAX(VASH3.UpdateStatusDate) FROM Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH3 WHERE VASH3.VehicleAssetID=VASH1.VehicleAssetID AND VASH3.UpdateStatusDate<VASH1.UpdateStatusDate), VASH1.UpdateStatusDate) 
              ELSE 0
       END AS 'MinutesOpen'
FROM 
       Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH1
WHERE
       VASH1.VehicleAssetID = '45793'
ORDER BY
       VASH1.UpdateStatusDate

Record Vehicle Update  Update  Minutes
        Asset   Status  Status 
ID      ID      ID      Date    Open
8720    45793   2   31:51.9 0
16087   45793   2   57:00.0 1117346
16711   45793   2   15:00.0 72198
16717   45793   2   45:00.0 1050
16956   45793   2   00:00.0 19455
17124   45793   2   53:00.0 11033
19592   45793   3   58:00.0 70385
19651   45793   3   00:00.0 0
21030   45793   2   00:00.0 0
20702   45793   3   12:00.0 22992
31711   45793   3   27:00.0 0
43226   45793   2   31:00.0 0
43274   45793   3   30:00.0 419
43434   45793   2   00:00.0 0
43349   45793   3   00:00.0 2520
43500   45793   3   30:00.0 0
43526   45793   2   00:00.0 0
43718   45793   2   32:00.0 4592
44214   45793   3   30:00.0 17098
44229   45793   2   23:00.0 0
44854   45793   3   30:00.0 18667
44942   45793   2   00:00.0 0
44988   45793   3   00:00.0 2040
45020   45793   2   50:00.0 0
45496   45793   3   00:00.0 15730
45509   45793   2   04:00.0 0
```

**Am I completely off track here on how to solve this problem the simplest way?**

Thanks for any/all help offered

Comment: Which platform are you using SQL on -- that can make a difference

Comment: thank you for the "off track" pun

Comment: Did you trying summing the Minutes Open and grouping by status id?? this can either be done using CTE or Temp tables or even an subquery

Comment: @Standin.Wolf -- that would not work -- since it is a running total it would give an "interesting" number

Comment: Which dbms is this for???  SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms.

Comment: @Hogan platform is SQLServer2012

Comment: @Eric SQLServer2012

Comment: Shouldn't the status alternate (2, 3, 2, 3)?  What does consecutive 2's mean?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested the solution I have found is:

```
WITH OffRoadDuration as 
(      
    SELECT
        VASH1.VehicleAssetID,
        VASH1.UpdateStatusID,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,VASH1.UpdateStatusDate, ISNULL(OA_VASH2.UpdateStatusDate,GETDATE()) ) AS OffRoadMinutes
    FROM Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH1
        OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH2
            WHERE VASH2.VehicleAssetID = VASH1.VehicleAssetID AND VASH2.UpdateStatusDate > VASH1.UpdateStatusDate
            ORDER BY VASH2.UpdateStatusDate ASC) AS OA_VASH2
    WHERE
        VASH1.VehicleAssetID='45793' 
)
SELECT 
    ORD.VehicleAssetID,
    ORD.UpdateStatusID,
    SUM(ORD.OffRoadMinutes) AS [OffRoadMinutes],
    ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,SUM(ORD.OffRoadMinutes))/1440,1) AS [OffRoadDays]
FROM
    OffRoadDuration ORD
GROUP BY 
    ORD.VehicleAssetID, ORD.UpdateStatusID
```

Thanks for all the help, much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You want a group by with lead()

```
  Select vehicle, sum(case when 

         updateStatusId=2
    then StatusWiseTimeDiff else 
    - StatusWiseTimeDiff end) from(
    Select vehicle, UpdateStatusID, 
     Sum(Case when lead(statusid) over 
        (partition by 
     vehicle order by updatestatusdate 
     asc)<>statusid  
     Then

    Date_Diff( Max(UpdateStatusDate), 
    Min(UpdateStatusDate))) as 
     StatusWiseTimeDiff from table 

      End from table
  group by vehicle, 
  )
```

Comment: I guess your answer is missing the time difference

Comment: Yeah you are right the Ops query was so long din see time difference was needed

Comment: This code does not come close to solving the problem.

Comment: What does that mean will you explain? The above query gives the output as each vehicles updatestatuswise time difference also with the outer query giving total timedifference of on and off road

Comment: But the problem involves a standard hills and valleys problem -- Let me explain, in the example data above there is only one vehicle but it's status changes over 10 times.  Your current code treats this as two cases -- your first version treated this as 1 case.  You have to find the end points by status change for each change and then "roll up" those results into to total values.  This is the problem.    For example if I was on road 3 times for 10 mins each the total would be 30 mins.

Comment: Descrete values of change did you mean ahh.. thats for whole set for a vehicle that I posted umm.. First roadon until roadoff time +second roadon until off time n so on.. Is this what required?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Himanshu - I've tried to get your code above to work, see my next comment, however it errors but I may have made mistakes in translating! I will post the error too.  However, I then noticed the additional 2 comments on the bottom of this answer, for a single vehicle I want 1 total for how long it was Off Road, and likewise a total time for how long it was On Road.  I originally tried to solve this in small increments, as Hogan puts it 'standard hills and valleys problem'

Comment: `SELECT 
 VASH.VehicleAssetID, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN VASH.UpdateStatusID=2 THEN VASH.StatusWiseTimeDiff ELSE - VASH.StatusWiseTimeDiff END)  AS Answer
FROM
(
    SELECT 
  VASH1.VehicleAssetID, 
  VASH1.UpdateStatusID, 
  SUM(CASE 
   WHEN LEAD(VASH1.UpdateStatusID) OVER (PARTITION BY VASH1.VehicleAssetID ORDER BY VASH1.UpdateStatusDate ASC)<>VASH1.UpdateStatusID 
   THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Max(VASH1.UpdateStatusDate),Min(VASH1.UpdateStatusDate))END) AS StatusWiseTimeDiff 
 FROM 
  dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory VASH1
 GROUP BY 
  VASH1.VehicleAssetID
 ) AS VASH`

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
Column 'Key2Live.dbo.VehicleAssetsStatusHistory.UpdateStatusID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.